# Repeat entry of citation when using Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to use Bibtex for some citations.

Contents of ref_list.bib

```
@inproceedings{Ng1999,
author = {Ng, Andrew Y. and Harada, Daishi and Russell, Stuart J.},
title = {Policy Invariance Under Reward Transformations: Theory and   Application to Reward Shaping},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the Sixteenth International Conference on    Machine Learning},
series = {ICML '99},
year = {1999},
publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann Publishers Inc.},
} 
@inproceedings{langley00,
author    = {P. Langley},
title     = {Crafting Papers on Machine Learning},
year      = {2000},
pages     = {1207--1216},
editor    = {Pat Langley},
booktitle     = {Proceedings of the 17th International Conference
          on Machine Learning (ICML 2000)},
address   = {Stanford, CA},
publisher = {Morgan Kaufmann}
}
```

Remaining Document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\bibliography{ref_list}
\bibliographystyle{icml2019}
\cite{Ng1999}
\cite{langley00}
```

The result I get in doing this is shown below:
[image]

As can be seen there is an additional mention of the references in the below line. I beleive this is a mistake since it does not seem desirable. How can this artifact be removed?

EDIT: Thanks to @Mico for their answer
I had not correctly understood the use of Bibtex. We use \cite when we need to mention the referenced paper (Usually in the body of the paper) and in the end we simply include the .bib file name to get an auto-generated list of the citations used in the main paper

Comment: Please make your example code compilable. From your current code snippe I would guess that  (Ng et al., 1999)  and (Langley, 2000)  are the results of the `\cite` command.

Comment: Yes, apologies I'll add the .bib file content

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package is deprecated. Don't use it. Instead, use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Comment: The citation call-outs are typeset below the formatted bibliography because -- by placing the `\cite` instructions *after* the `\bibliography` instruction -- that is what you're instructing LaTeX to do. If you do not want the two citation call-outs in that location, don't provide the corresponding `\cite` instructions.

Comment: @Mico Thank you

Comment: If you just want an entry to show up in the bibliography, but not have the inline citation generated, use `\nocite`.